# Adding HTML within an image title attribute

Tags: images, css, html, title, customization

I am using some jquery which applies an overlay on an image on hover. The script uses content from the image's title attribute to display over the image. When I tested this locally, it seemed to work, and I could style the text within `title=""` however, I'm now trying to get it working in WordPress, and it doesn't seem to let me style the text within the title attribute.

```
<img src="img.png" title="<h1>Title heading</h1><hr><h2>Title sub heading</h2>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all i'd recommend you stop using `title` attribute for html container purpose:

> Image title (and the element name speaks for itself) should provide
>   additional information and follow the rules of the regular title: it
>   should be relevant, short, catchy, and concise (a title “offers
>   advisory information about the element for which it is set“). In
>   FireFox and Opera it pops up when you hover over an image

In order to get things works you can use `data-` attribute (very good "intermediate" [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/) about data-attribute with example how to use)

Considering [[Can data-* attribute contain HTML tags?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699276/can-data-attribute-contain-html-tags) it's valid to use `data-` attributes with HTML, and, as recommended under the refference above - take into account character escape.